# ¿Cómo eliminar espacios en blanco arriba y abajo de un iframe de video perteneciente a Vimeo?

Tags: css, video, iframe, videoview

Tengo la siguiente estructura HTML:

```
<main class="video">

    <div class="video__contenedor">

        <div class="video__descripcion">
            <div id="video__descripcion__contenido">Descripcion</div>
            <button class="video__descripcion__boton">Ver Más Información</button>

        </div>

        <div class="video__contenido">

            <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/88509099" width="640" height="480" allow="autoplay; fullscreen; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>

        </div>

    </div>

</main>
```

El código CSS que pertebece a cada clase contenedora es el siguiente:

```
.video {
    display        : flex;
    justify-content: center;
    font-family    : Montserrat;
}

.video__contenedor {
    width           : 80%;
    background-color: #158eff;
    padding         : 15px;
    border-radius   : 10px;
    color           : white;
    margin-top      : 20px;
    font-size       : 18px;
}

.video__contenido {
    margin-top: 20px;
}

iframe {
    width: 100%;
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La forma en que consigo que el iframe de Vimeo no se salga de mi contenedor es con `width: 100%`, pero esto hace que me queden unos espacios a los lados o arriba y abajo (en dependencia del ancho de la pantalla) los cuales señalé con rectángulos rojos en la imagen, estos espacios no los consigo eliminar pese a haber probado con distintas propiedades CSS. ¿Alguien sabe si es posible y en caso de serlo qué debería hacer? Gracias de antemano

Comment: Yo lo veo bastante bien.. ¿puedes pegar una imagen en tu pregunta señalando a que espacios en blanco te refieres?

Comment: @masterguru ya añadí la imagen a la pregunta y di más detalles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encontré la solución a mi problema haciendo uso de los estilos en línea que agrega de la opción: "responsive" dentro de las opciones para compartir video que integra Vimeo. Básicamente había que realizar lo siguiente:

Contener el `iframe` en un div con las siguientes propiedades CSS:

```
.video__contenido__vimeo {
    padding : 75% 0 0 0;
    position: relative;
}
```

Agregar las siguientes propiedades CSS al `iframe`:

```
iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top     : 0;
    left    : 0;
    width   : 100%;
    height  : 100%;
}
```

La estrutura HTML queda así:

```
<main class="video">

    <div class="video__contenedor">

        <div class="video__descripcion">
            <div id="video__descripcion__contenido">Descripcion</div>
            <button class="video__descripcion__boton">Ver Más Información</button>

        </div>

        <div class="video__contenido">

            <div class="video__contenido__vimeo">
                <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/88509099?h=538cd3a41c" width="640" height="480" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

</main>
```